# Type error: a def that works only with str but not int

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a biginner in Python and I have to find the reach error here. I know that the trouble is in how am I calling the fuction, it does not have to be a number after the line `if expresion [i] == '1':` because is not a str, is a int so in that way, should work but i dont know how to change it

```
def tiene_uno(expresion):
    n = str(len(expresion))
    i = 0
    tiene = False
    while (i<n) and not tiene:
        if expresion[i] == '1':
            tiene = True
        i += 1
    return tiene


tiene_uno('UNSAM 2020')
tiene_uno('La novela 1984 de George Orwell')
tiene_uno(1984)
```

while (i<n) and not tiene:
error '<' not supported between instances of int and str

Comment: Looks like you're defining a function, but I don't see the `def tiene_uno` line. Could you please include that in your code?

Comment: so sorry! typing error

Comment: Is it supposed to have the backtick before the `def`?

Comment: The `len` function isn't defined for integers. It looks like you're trying to see if the digit `1` is in the input string. Is that correct?

Comment: yes! that is correct but when it gets to tiene_uno(1984) shows this error
while (i<n) and not tiene: error '<' not supported between instances of int and str

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental error is that the result of `n = str(len(expression))` is a string, not an integer. You cannot compare a string with an integer using `<`. You probably should have `n = len(str(expression))` instead.

If you just want to see if the character `'1'` is in the input string, you're doing a lot more work, I think, than you need. Try this out:

```
def tiene_uno(expression):
    return '1' in str(expression)
```

If you're in a class, and you're being asked to do it the way you have there, then I would recommend this:

```
def tiene_uno(expression):

    # Always scrub your function inputs!
    working_expression = str(expression)
    n = len(working_expression)
    i = 0
    tiene = False
    while (i < n and not tiene):
        if working_expression[i] == '1':
            tiene = True
        i += 1
    return tiene
```